# Can someone explain how the lambdas in lambdarank work?

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm

I am reading [From RankNet to LambdaRank to LambdaMART: An Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqJuE.png). Section 4.1 describes LabdaRank. The last paragraph on page 8 and first paragraph of page 9 describe how the score ($s_i$) of each document/URL($u_i$) changed. The example assumes that $U_i$ is more relevant than $U_j$. According to me, this should result in the increase in $s_i$ and a decrease in $s_j$, but the equations for change in $s_i$($\delta s_i$) and $\delta s_j$ show the exact opposite affect i.e. $s_i$ decreases and $s_j$ increases. Reference image from the paper (pg 9):[image] I think assuming that $\lambda$ will always be positive is incorrect. In fact equation 6 suggests that $\lambda$ will be negative. Could someone please point out the flaw in my understanding?